# C Programming: Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: c, linux, pipe, ipc

The program i am trying to write is trying to demonstrate how IPC works on Linux, but i keep getting a core dump error. It compiles fine and will run up until the last output statement in the parent process.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <string.h>


 #define SHM_SIZE 15

int main (int argc, char ** argv[]) {
     pid_t pid; //pid variable of type pid
     int shmid; //shared memory id
     int key = 1776; //randomly chosen key
     char *shm; //shared memory name 

     int pipefd[2];
     char buff;

     pid = fork(); //creating child process
     pipe(pipefd); //creating pipe


if (pid < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); 
    return -1;
} else if (pid == 0) {
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0); 
    shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

    char *n = (char *) shm;

    printf("hello i am the child process. my pid is %d. what is your name?: ", getpid());
    scanf("%s", n);
    printf("\n");

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

    close(pipefd[1]);
    printf("pipe opened on child end");
    printf("\n");
    while(read(pipefd[0], &buff, 1) > 0) {
            write(1, &buff, 1);
    }    
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    printf("pipe successfully closed");
    printf("\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

} else {
    shmid = shmget(key, SHM_SIZE, 0777 | IPC_CREAT);
    shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

    wait(NULL);

    printf("\nThis is Child's Parent. My pid is %d. Nice to me you %s.\n", getpid(), shm);
    printf("\n");

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    close(pipefd[0]);
    printf("pipe open on parent end");
    printf("\n");
    write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
    close(pipefd[1]);
    printf("pipe successfully closed");
    wait(NULL);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
return 0;
}
```

Does it have something to do with my args[]? Such as could i be accessing memory out of reach? Or am trying to access some invalid pointer?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Create the pipe before the fork, otherwise you are creating 2 pipes

Comment: your `main` signature is wrong... that should be `char* argv[]` or `char** argv`

Comment: Why you think shm in printf is a null terminated string?

Comment: regarding: `int main (int argc, char ** argv[])`  the second parameter: `char **argv[]` is effectively: `char ***argv`  this is not correct.  Suggest using: `char **argv`  or `char *argv[]`

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]`  with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameter was actually entered by the user.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding, 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  Treat the closing brace '}' as a separate statement.  3) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do..while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful. 2) when using the format specifiers '%[...]' and/or '%s', always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers append a NUL byte to the input and to avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow (which would result in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event)

Comment: regarding: `write(1, "\n", 1);` and `printf("\n");` are both might CPU cycle expensive ways to write `puts("");`

Comment: regarding: `write(1, &buff, 1);`  this is a mighty cpu cycle way to write: `putc(buff)`

Comment: Suggest using `ftok()` for creating the 'key' for the shared memory.  You might also want to make use of `shmat()` and `shmdt()` for attaching/detaching the shared memory to each process.  Before each process exit, it should call `shmctl()` with the `IPC_RMID` parameter so when the last process using the shared memory is exited, the shared memory will be destroyed (and not before all using processes are exited)

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.  For instance the `err.h` header file.  Suggest  removing such `#include`  statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code

1. Create the pipe **before** the `fork`. You create the pipe twice, once for
   the parent process and one for the child process. That makes no sense, the pipe
   that the child created cannot be used by the parent. The pipe must already
   exists so that the child inherits the file descriptors when the child is
   created.
2. Usually the parent creates the shared memory and the child gets the `shmid`
   from the parent when it does the `fork`. Otherwise you will have to synchronize
   the child and parent. So I would put the creation of the shared memory before
   the `fork`, so that the child inherits the `shmid` from the parent.
3. In the line `char *n = (char *) shm;` the cast is not needed, `shm` is
   already a `char*`.
4. In the parent block after the `fork`, you do `wait(NULL);` and then proceed to
   write into the pipe. That makes no sense and you block both parent and child.
   The child blocks on `read` because the parent hasn't send anything through the
   pipe, yet. And the parent blocks on `wait`, because the child never exits and thus
   cannot send anything through the pipe. The parent must **first** send data
   through the pipe, then `wait` for the child to exit.
5. In the child block you do `scanf("%s", n);`, you are not protecting you
   against buffer overflows. `scanf("%14s", n)` would be better. Also you are not
   checking if `scanf` read anything at all. If the user presses
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> then `stdin` is closed, `scanf` fails. In that case
   `n` might not be `'\0'`-terminated and this would lead to undefined behaviour
   when the parent tries to print it. So it would be better:

   ```
   if(scanf("%14s", n) != 1) // avoid buffer overflow
   {   
       fprintf(stderr, "Child: cannot read from stdin\n");
       n[0] = 0; // 0-terminating
   }
   ```
6. In the parent block after the `fork`, you do `wait` twice, why?
7. Your `main` is wrong, it should be

   ```
   int main(int argc, char **argv);
   ```
8. The parent sends the contents of `argv[1]` to the child through the pipe, but
   you fail to check if `argv[1]` is not `NULL`. Use this at the start of the
   program:

   ```
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
   ```

So the correct version would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <string.h>


 #define SHM_SIZE 15

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
     pid_t pid; //pid variable of type pid
     int shmid; //shared memory id
     char *shm; //shared memory name 

     if(argc != 2)
     {
         fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s string\n", argv[0]);
         return 1;
     }

     int pipefd[2];
     char buff;

     // create shared memory before the fork,
     // otherwise you will need to syncronize parent
     // and child

     pipe(pipefd); //creating pipe before the fork

     // parent creates shared memory, child inherits shmid
     // after fork
     shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SHM_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | 0666); 

     pid = fork(); //creating child process


    if (pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed"); 
        return 1; // return -1 would be the same as return 255
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);

        char *n = shm; // shm is already a char*

        printf("hello i am the child process. my pid is %d. what is your name?: ", getpid());
        if(scanf("%14s", n) != 1) // avoid buffer overflow
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Child: cannot read from stdin\n");
            n[0] = 0; // 0-terminating
        }
        printf("\n");

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

        close(pipefd[1]);
        printf("pipe opened on child end");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Parent sends: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        while(read(pipefd[0], &buff, 1) > 0) {
                write(1, &buff, 1);
        }    
        write(1, "\n", 1);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        printf("pipe successfully closed");
        printf("\n");
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {
        shm = shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        printf("pipe open on parent end");
        printf("\n");
        write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
        close(pipefd[1]);
        printf("pipe successfully closed");

        // not we wait for child to exit
        wait(NULL);

        printf("\nThis is Child's Parent. My pid is %d. Nice to me you %s.\n", getpid(), shm);
        printf("\n");

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
$ ./b "message to child: stop playing video games!"
pipe open on parent end
hello i am the child process. my pid is 10969. what is your name?: Pablo

pipe opened on child end
Parent sends: message to child: stop playing video games!
pipe successfully closed
pipe successfully closed
This is Child's Parent. My pid is 10968. Nice to me you Pablo.
```

Answer (score -1):

You are reading and writing from the same end of the pipe you create. Common practice is to read from end [1] and write to end [0]. Tell me if that helps. Additionally, it is also common practice to not have too much going on between the child and parent processes. Attempting to execute code in between segments (parent and child) usually ends up with a segmentation fault, even if your code compiles.